# How to get nested properties

Tags: c#, reflection

I want to retrieve a PropertyInfo, Here the code :

```
string propertyName="Text";
PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

it works fine but if I want to retrieve nested properties, it returns null :

```
string propertyName="DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors";
PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Is there any way to get nested properties ?

Best Regards,

Florian

Edit : I have a new problem now, I want to get a property which is an array :

```
string propertyName="DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns";
PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
```

Thank you

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes:

```
public PropertyInfo GetProp(Type baseType, string propertyName)
{
    string[] parts = propertyName.Split('.');

    return (parts.Length > 1) 
        ? GetProp(baseType.GetProperty(parts[0]).PropertyType, parts.Skip(1).Aggregate((a,i) => a + "." + i)) 
        : baseType.GetProperty(propertyName);
}
```

Called:

```
PropertyInfo pi = GetProp(control.GetType(), "DisplayLayout.Override.RowSelectors");
```

Recursion for the win!

Comment: Thank you !

I want to know how get a property via an indexor : 

string propertyName="DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns";
PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);

Answer (score 3):

Just do the same again on the `PropertyType` you just got for the property (and repeat as often as you need):

```
PropertyInfo property = GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
PropertyInfo nestedProperty = property.PropertyType.GetProperty(nestedPropertyName)
```

Comment: Yes, I forgot the PropertyType bit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but you have to do the "whole thing" for each level, meaning:

- Get the property from your object type
- Get the type of that property
- Rinse and repeat :)