# How to access of an array item property using Reflection?

Tags: c#, reflection

further to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111725/how-to-get-nested-properties), I have a new problem now, I want to get a property which is an array :

```
string propertyName="DisplayLayout.Bands[0].Columns";
PropertyInfo pi = control.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName)
```

But actually, it returns null.

Best Regards,

Florian
Edit : Sorry for the lack of precision :$ I access to Bands property thanks to the answers of my precent question. My real problem is to access at the 'Columns' property which is a property of type 'Band'. I hope it's more clear.

EDIT2 : here an example :

```
PropertyInfo t = control.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Value[i].Nom.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0]);
PropertyInfo property = control.GetType().GetProperty(entry.Value[i].Nom.Split(new char[] { '.' })[0]);
PropertyInfo nestedProperty = property.PropertyType.GetProperty("Bands");
```

in nestedProperty I have Bands (Infragistics.UltraWinGrid.BandsCollection Bands) but I don't manage to access Bands[0] and the 'Column' Property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax `Bands[0]` is an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) access.  Indexers are a properties that take parameters.  C# doesn't allow properties with parameters to be accessed by name, but allows indexer syntax for the property matching the name given in a [DefaultMemberAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.defaultmemberattribute.aspx) on type type.  To get the `PropertyInfo` for the indexer in your example, you could write:

```
PropertyInfo nestedProperty = property.PropertyType.GetProperty("Bands");
var defaultMember = (DefaultMemberAttribute)Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(nestedProperty.PropertyType, typeof(DefaultMemberAttribute));
var nestedIndexer = nestedProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty(defaultMember.MemberName);
```

In order to get a value from the indexer, you will need to supply a second parameter to [PropertyInfo.GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b05d59ty.aspx) with the values to pass in:

```
var value = nestedIndexer.GetValue(bands, new object[] { 0 });
```

Comment: Thank you. Yet, the line nestedProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty(defaultMember.MemberName); 
returns 'null'. In the 'quickwatch' editor, the 'value' column indicates 'nestedProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty(defaultMember.MemberName)' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException' System.Reflection.PropertyInfo {System.Reflection.AmbiguousMatchException}'

Comment: @Florian: Use the overload of GetProperty that takes in a list of argument types for overload resolution: nestedProperty.PropertyType.GetProperty(defaultMember.MemberName, new Type[] { typeof(int) })

Comment: It works very well. Thank you !!! just a last question. In your example, in the last line :

 var value = nestedIndexer.GetValue(bands, new object[] { 0 });

What is the reference to bands ??

Answer (score 3):

When you refer to a Type of some instance, you will only get "reflective" access to the methods, properties, etc. of said type.

Hence, the dot notation is not supported as you are basically touching 3 types, some control, some collection of Bands and a Band instance.

In other words, you can ask the control for the property "Bands" or the type of "Band" for the property "Columns", but no dot-notation.

Answer (score 2):

You are going too fast.  There a three types and three properties here, you'll need to use GetType and GetProperty three times.